# Перенос bat с windows 10 на windows 7, ошибка с curl

Tags: cmd, windows-10, ssl, bat, windows-7

На моей Windows 10 разработан bat для curl, отрабатывает на ура.
Но когда я переношу её на windows 7, то выходит ошибка SSL.
На windows 10 уже автоматом стоит curl, а на windows 7 пришлось установить самому.
Такую же версию установить не получилось...

Пример кода:
`curl -X POST https://MySite -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "MyJSON" --output "C:\MyFile.txt"`

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить данную проблему?

curl windows 10 = curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
curl windows 7 = curl 7.78.0 ... (Скачал и разархивировал в System32)

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**
После добавления `--cacert` ошибка стала 77
`curl --cacert "C:\MyCert.cer" -X POST ...`
[image: Ошибка 77]

После добавления `curl -k -v -X POST ...`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После снижения TLS, что уже пробовал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для сравнения на Win10 `curl -v ...`
[image: curl win10]

**МОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ**
Я посчитал проще обновить Win7 до Win10.
Но для кого это не решение, я вопрос не удаляю. Надеюсь Вам помогут в ответах.

Comment: Ок, я установил curl 7.55.1 на windows 7, но проблема остается

Comment: В windows 10 стоит совсем другой curl. Он собран c родным движком Microsoft и использует сертификаты из Windows Trust Store. Вам нужно раздобыть сертификат, которым подписан сертификат вашего сайта и указать этот сертификат в опции `cacert`: `curl --cacert <path_to_cert> -X POST ...`

Comment: @PakUula, я скачал сертификат с помощью  Google Chrome, разные вариации попробовал. Скачал в разных кодировках. Сначала сертификат самого сайта, потом сертификат CA сайта. Ошибка теперь 77, скрин добавил в обновление

Comment: У вас, похоже, вообще нет сертификатов в `curl`.  Чтобы не возиться с установкой сертификатов, предлагаю план Б - отключить проверку сертификатов: `curl -k ...`

Comment: @PakUula, я решил обновить до Win10, но попробую

Comment: @PakUula, увы, но это не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте распаковать curl в какую-нибудь другую папку и добавьте `curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\bin` в PATH.

Comment: @PakUula, в PATH добавлено, иначе бы ругалось на неизвестную команду

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

Судя по выводу `curl -v` ваш клиент начинает с TLS 1.3, на что сервер отвечает `failure` и прерывает handshake.

Попробуйте понизить версию TLS в запросе: до TLS 1.2 `curl.exe -v -k --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 ...`

или до TLS 1.1 `curl.exe -v -k --tlsv1.1 --tls-max 1.1 ...`

По идее, TLS 1.2 должно быть достаточно.

`* * *`

Вы пишете что-то удивительное.

Для проверки я скачал [culr-7.78.0](https://curl.se/windows/dl-7.78.0/curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw.zip), распаковал и протестировал.

```
PS:tmp> .\curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe -V
curl 7.78.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.78.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.0 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.44.0 libgsasl/1.10.0
Release-Date: 2021-07-21
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli gsasl HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

В качестве объекта я взял сайт https://self-signed.badssl.com/ с самоподписным сертификатом.

Сначала запуск curl с параметрами по умолчанию:

```
PS:tmp> .\curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe https://self-signed.badssl.com/
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Как и ожидалось, curl отказался работать с сайтом из-за невозможности верифицировать сертификат.

Вторая попытка. Я скачал сертификат сайта и указал его в опции `cacert`. Так как сертификат самоподписной, то он сам себе CA cert.

```
PS:tmp> .\curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe --cacert .\self-signed.crt.cer https://self-signed.badssl.com/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

Работает.

Третья попытка. Отключить проверку сертификата `-k`:

```
PS:tmp> .\curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\curl-7.78.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe -k https://self-signed.badssl.com/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

Тоже работает.

Либо вы что-то не то скачали, либо не так установили, либо что-то недоговариваете. `curl -k` обязан работать.

Comment: Я скачал Вашу версию для 32 разрядной версии Windows. Для тестирования взял Ваш сайт. `--cacert` не работает, ошибка 60. `-k` работает, выводит страницу HTML. На нужный мне сайт `-k` не отрабатывает, всё та же ошибка 35

Comment: Было скачано из https://curl.se/windows/, распаковал в System32, добавил в PATH

Comment: @MaksimMaslennikov добавьте в вопрос вывод `curl -k -v ...` - будет более подробная диагностика.

Comment: добавил в запрос, вывод скрин в обновлении

Comment: @MaksimMaslennikov добавил **UPD** с понижением версии TLS.

Comment: Я уже пытался снизить TLS. Для показания добавил в обновление

Comment: @MaksimMaslennikov Тогда у меня идей нет. Нужно пробовать руками. Если хотите, пришлите мне адрес вашего сервера на pakuula at gmail.com

Comment: Увы, но это не наш сервер, а государственный. Запрос отправляет к ним по API данные. Всё что я создал, то работает на моей Win10 машине. Но когда переношу на Win7 (изменяя все пути в bat), то ругается `curl`. Все остальные данные перепроверены по методичке данного сервера, на обоих машинах совпадают нужные требования

Comment: @MaksimMaslennikov тогда вам нетрудно будет показать `curl -v` с вашей Win10? Для сравнения

Comment: Обновил информацию `curl -v` для Win10

Comment: @MaksimMaslennikov как оказалось, это не поможет. В Windows 10 другой SSL движок, с другим диагностическим выводом. В отличие от OpenSSL он не печатает ни версию TLS, ни согласованный набор криптопримитивов. У меня закончились версии ))

Comment: Всё равно, спасибо за помощь